# WiFi scan data is not working in android M

Tags: gps, android-location, android-6.0-marshmallow, wifimanager

I want to develop WiFi scan app. The app is working fine in below android M. Above android M, I used `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` its working fine if I switch ON my GPS. If I switch off my location the WiFi scan is not working Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Android 6.0, GPS must be enabled to get any results from wifi scans.

You can check this thread (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=185370) for further information. It appears it is an intended behaviour:

> Thanks for the suggestion. Our development team has looked into this bug and decided that it is working as per the design.
>   WifiManager#getScanResults() returns an empty list if location is turned off for the device.

It sucks, I agree, but that's how it is for now.